# malt parser gives assertion error when using it with nltk

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, malt-parser

I am using malt parser with python nltk. I have successfully downloaded the training data and updated the latest nltk. When I call the malt parser it gives me an asertion error. Below is the code from python which includes the traceback as well.

```
 mp = MaltParser("C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.8.1","C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.7.2",additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    mp = MaltParser("C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.8.1","C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.7.2",additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.malt_jars = find_maltparser(parser_dirname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 72, in find_maltparser
    assert malt_dependencies.issubset(_jars)
AssertionError
>>>
```

Comment: Have you setup: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software#malt-parser ?

Comment: Do you have ['log4j.jar', 'libsvm.jar', 'liblinear-1.8.jar'] in `C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.8.1`?

Comment: What is the output of `dir C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.8.1/` on the command prompt?

Comment: BTW, the second parameter is the trained `.mco` file not another malt-parser, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L104

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, please update your question with the above answers to the questions in the comments, and we'll try out best to help you. We need to know these information to better help you with the question.

Comment: My hunch is that this line is causing the problem change the slash to backslash and it should work: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L69

Comment: Thanks for spotting the bug!

Comment: @alvas the second parameter is the path to the mco file it is not another malt-parser. plus I also have the log4j.jar,liblinear-1.8.jar and libvsm.jar in the given path

Comment: @alvas output of dir C:/Users/mustufain/Desktop/Python Files/maltparser-1.8.1/ : Invalid switch - "Users"

Comment: Ah ha, silly me... In windows, it's `dir C:\Users\mustufain\Desktop\Python Files\maltparser-1.8.1\` What's the output of that?

Comment: @alvas it says the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @alvas I am not getting an exception now I figured it out as I have changed the name of maltparser-1.8.1.jar to malt.jar file but as I looked through the code of line which was giving me this assertion error I renamed it to maltparser-1.8.1.jar and It went fine

Comment: Please look at http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/

Comment: import nltk
 from nltk.parse import malt
 parser = nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser(working_dir="D:/Python Files/maltparser-1.7.2",mco="engmalt.poly-1.7.mco",additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])
 txt = "This is a test sentence"
 graph=parser.raw_parse(txt)

Comment: Put it in the question... -_-|||

Comment: @alvas I have updated my malt.py file and when I run the above code it gives me this exception : File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\dependencygraph.py", line 378
    "The graph doesn't contain a node "
UserWarning: The graph doesn't contain a node that depends on the root element.

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

Comment: Please see new answer!

Answer (score 2):

**`TL;DR`** (In **PYTHON3**!!):

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.poly-1.7.mco', 'C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\engmalt.poly-1.7.mco')
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://maltparser.org/dist/maltparser-1.8.1.zip', 'C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\maltparser-1.8.1.zip')
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\maltparser-1.8.1.zip')
zfile.extractall('C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\maltparser-1.8.1\\')
```

Then:

```
from nltk.parse import malt
mp = malt.MaltParser('C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\maltparser-1.8.1\\', "C:\\Users\\mustufain\\Desktop\\engmalt.poly-1.7.mco")
mp.parse_one('I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()).tree()
```

Comment: Thanks @L3viathan for the edit! There's an extensive answer on: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1294 too.

Comment: Maybe you should link that in your answer as well then. Greet Saarbrücken from me!

Comment: @L3viathan No problem ;P

Answer (score 1):

If all the download and environmental variable setup is done correctly, most probably it's how file/dir path are splitted in the `nltk.parse.malt.py`, at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L69 that splits the directory and filename specifically for linux:

```
def find_maltparser(parser_dirname):
    """
    A module to find MaltParser .jar file and its dependencies.
    """
    if os.path.exists(parser_dirname): # If a full path is given.
        _malt_dir = parser_dirname
    else: # Try to find path to maltparser directory in environment variables.
        _malt_dir = find_dir(parser_dirname, env_vars=('MALT_PARSER',))
    # Checks that that the found directory contains all the necessary .jar
    malt_dependencies = ['','','']
    _malt_jars = set(find_jars_within_path(_malt_dir))
    _jars = set(jar.rpartition('/')[2] for jar in _malt_jars)
    malt_dependencies = set(['log4j.jar', 'libsvm.jar', 'liblinear-1.8.jar'])

    assert malt_dependencies.issubset(_jars)
    assert any(filter(lambda i: i.startswith('maltparser-') and i.endswith('.jar'), _jars))
    return list(_malt_jars)
```

The bug has been fixed and in the process of merging at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1292

Changing this line:

```
_jars = set(jar.rpartition('/')[2] for jar in _malt_jars)
```

to this should solve your problem =)

```
_jars = set(os.path.split(jar)[1] for jar in _malt_jars)
```

---

For the answer not related to the code itself but how you have setup the environment variables or downloaded and saved the malt parser directories or files, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1294

Comment: It didnot work I have changed the line in malt.py and restart it, it still gives me an assertion erorr when i load the malt-parser

Comment: It gives me this new assertion error after changing the line in malt.py: assert any(filter(lambda i: i.startswith('maltparser-') and i.endswith('.jar'), _jars))
AssertionError

Comment: It is throwing exception at this line : malt_dependencies = set(['log4j.jar', 'libsvm.jar', 'liblinear-1.8.jar'])